# Error when importing variable from different script from different directory

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, python-import

I was working on a project where I was training a neural network and displaying information using a GUI in Python. However, I have a constant problem with importing modules. This is the error I get when trying to run Visualizer.Main

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/user/SplineTrajectoryGenerator/Visualizer/Main.py", line 3, in <module>

from Visualizer.Field import Field

File "/home/user/SplineTrajectoryGenerator/Visualizer/Field.py", line 3, in <module>

from Visualizer.Utils import loadImage

File "/home/user/SplineTrajectoryGenerator/Visualizer/Utils.py", line 3, in <module>

from NeuralNetworks.Pose import Pose2D

File "/home/user/SplineTrajectoryGenerator/NeuralNetworks/Pose.py", line 4, in <module>

from Visualizer.Utils import constraint

ImportError: cannot import name 'constraint'
```

However, the strange thing is that the variable exists and can be found in Utils.py in the Visualizer folder. I was told that using the _init__.py
allows a directory to be used as a module to import methods and classes from scripts in other directories. I'm still confused about why this error happens when the variable exists. For reference the tree of all the files look like this.

```
.

├── NeuralNetworks

│   ├── __init__.py

│   ├──Main.py

│   └──Pose.py

├──README.md

└── Visualizer

├── Assets

│   ├── Field.png

│   └── Robot.png

├──Field.py

├── __init__.py

├──Main.py

├──Robot.py

└──Utils.py
```

In case you need to see the scripts, I have attached the whole folder below with this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1o81dpagPakhOGUSbrjuJWfX4HWhAyWmH?usp=sharing). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a cyclic dependency between `Visualizer.Utils` and NeuralNetworks.Pose`:

> from Visualizer.Utils import loadImage
>
> File "/home/user/SplineTrajectoryGenerator/Visualizer/Utils.py", line
>   3, in
>
> from NeuralNetworks.Pose import Pose2D
>
> File "/home/user/SplineTrajectoryGenerator/NeuralNetworks/Pose.py",
>   line 4, in
>
> from Visualizer.Utils import constraint

Python does not support cyclic dependencies - and that's actually a GoodThing(tm) since those are design issues (two modules should not depend on each other). The canonical solution is to create a new module for objects (classes, functions, whatever) that are necessary to both modules (ie in your case create a distinct module for 'constraint').